# Logical volume spaning two drives with a dual drive usb dock?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, lvm

I am researching making a single logical volume spanning 2 external drives. External RAID enclosures seem a bit expensive and I don't need RAID. Could I use a multi-drive USB dock ([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07415KV63))? They seem cheaper and useful to have around. It would seem I could. I imagine these devices would allow you to detect and mount both drives separately and simultaneously. However, I haven't used dual drive docks like this before, so I wanted to check.

For example, I would have two 1TB drives that would slot in the dock. The dock would detect the drives, then I would mount them and (if necessary) decrypt them. They show up as one 2TB volume. When I was finished, I would unmount the drives and remove them from the dock.

Would that all work or is there something I'm missing? Is there any disadvantage to this set up versus two drives in separate USB enclosures connected to the same computer at two different USB ports?

I'm planning on mostly using the drives on a Debian machine, so my current plan is LVM (maybe with LUKS for encryption). However, I'm open to suggestions, especially if LVM won't work here for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create a volume spanning more than one drive, you do in fact need RAID -- can't do it without it. You can use LVM on top of that if you'd like, but LVM can't do it on its own.

This is quick, easy, and simple to do with Linux MD:

1. Make sure you have MD tools installed:

`$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install mdadm`

2. Know which 2 drives you want to use. For example here, let's say it's `/dev/sdx` and `/dev/sdy`. We're going to zap the partition tables and use both disks partition-less:

`$ sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sdx && sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sdy`

3. Create your MD RAID 0 array (assuming here this is your first and only MD array, so assuming "md0". Increase md number as necessary).

`$ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=stripe --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdx /dev/sdy`

4. Verify your RAID array exists with the commands `cat /proc/mdstat` and `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0`

From this point, you can treat "/dev/md0" as one big disk. Create a LVM volume on it, or just partition it as you wish (e.g. `mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0`). Same goes with mounting, `mount /dev/md0 /media/my-usb-raid`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is wrong. I won't downvote as I'll add my own, but LVM negates the need to RAID.

Comment: LVM (logical volume manager) works by enumerating pv's (physical volumes) which it can the group together into one or more vg's (volume groups) which can then be allocated into 1 or more lv's (logical volumes). The key takeaway is that you can use 2+ physical disks as volumes and combine them into a volume group without RAID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work - provided your dock does let you see both drives at the same time - the docks I have used behave this way, so I posit its likely yours will as well.

I might have concerns about sharing the bandwidth if a single USB port - it might be beneficial to use 2 docks  and get double the USB bandwidth.

There might also be some messing around to rescan the devices to enable LVM I guess - depending on the version of Linux and state of the drives.  I suspect it will work seamlessly  if the drives are always connected - but if not rescanning the VG's and LV's would make the data accessible.